# How to hide a button and how to have a new tab redirection on it?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm working as an intern for a company on GeoNode 2.8. I have to hide the `Download Layer` button if the user is not in the permission list. The previous intern made it in an older version of `Geonode` by adding a `{% get_obj_perms request.user for resource.layer as "perms" %}` before the button display function. But when I add it on my version of GeoNode, it didn't change anything and the button still there.

```
{% if resource.storeType != "remoteStore" %}
    {% get_obj_perms request.user for resource.layer as "layer_perms" %}
    <li class="list-group-item">
    {% if links or links_download %}
       <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#download-layer">{% trans "Download Layer" %}</button>
    {% else %}
      {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block" id="request-download">{% trans "Request Download" %}</button>
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endif %}
```

Second part, I have a button in a navbar with a redirection like this 
`<li><a href="{% url "help" %}">{% trans "Help" %}</a></li>`

My issue is the next one, how can I have a redirection but in a new tab, I thought I could use `target = _blank` but it's django and it doesn't work.
like this:
`<li><a target= "_blank" href="{% url "help" %}">{% trans "Help" %}</a></li>`

I think it's something to change in the `urls.py` but I'm new in it so I don't know how to add this redirection.

```
    url(r'^help/$',
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name='help.html'),
        name='help'),
```

Comment: Have you loaded your template tags file that contains the get_obj_perms function? i..e `{% load my_tags %}`

Comment: @urbanespaceman yes I did

Comment: OK, that was my only initial thought. Maybe post your template tags file as well though so we can see what the `get_obj_perms` is actually trying to do, and how it is set up.

Comment: @urbanespaceman I add it to the post, check it out

Comment: I don't see any `get_obj_perms` function there ... are you by any chance using django-guardian? If so, maybe your `load`statement is incorrect if you're loading base_tags - see here? https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/guardian.templatetags.guardian_tags.html

Comment: @urbanespaceman I'm loading guardians too in the file

Comment: OK, then I'm out of suggestions, sorry.

Comment: can you check if you have included `'django.core.context_processors.request'
` in your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR in settings file?

Comment: Also, where are you using `layer_perms` obtained from `get_obj_perms` to validate the permission of the user?

Comment: @Sanip it's in it but it's in comment, is it normal ?

Comment: If it is commented, then there is no mechanism to check if the user has the required permission on the object. In the above code, the permissions of the user in that object is called but not used. So i think you need to undo the comment in the code.

Comment: @Sanip even if I undo the comment it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you check the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have fetched the permissions of the user on the specified object as

```
{% get_obj_perms request.user for resource.layer as "layer_perms" %}
```

But you have not used the permissions obtained from this line. So you need to check if the user has a permission (e.g. can_view, can_download, etc.) on the layer object.

You can change your code as so:

```
{% if resource.storeType != "remoteStore" %}
    {% get_obj_perms request.user for resource.layer as "layer_perms" %}
    <li class="list-group-item">

    {% if links or links_download %}
       {% if "can_download" in layer_perms %} # change here, check if user has required permissions
           <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#download-layer">{% trans "Download Layer" %}</button>
       {% endif %} # close the condition
    {% else %}
      {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block" id="request-download">{% trans "Request Download" %}</button>
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endif %}
```

Make sure you change your code as per your requirement.

For further reference, you can have a look at [guardian-template-tags](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/guardian.templatetags.guardian_tags.html)

Comment: effectively, compare to the older version, I have to add an `if` statement, and change the ```get_obj_perms```.

Comment: I put `{% get_obj_perms request.user for resource.get_self_resource as "layer_perms" %}`

and the if was `{% if "download_resourcebase" in layer_perms %}`

Answer (score 0):

You should use your functions `{% if "download_resourcebase" in layer_perms %}` and use this by change the `download` by what you want like `change_resourcebase` etc.